# iOS VIMVideoPlayerView can't load vimeo videos

Tags: ios, vimeo

I'm making an iOS app in Objective C which has to load video with vimeo urls. I wanted to use a video player and I used this : https://github.com/vimeo/VIMVideoPlayer.
I follow the read me instructions, however I 'm not able to read vimeo videos, I got an error:

> Video player Status Failed: error = Error
>   Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11828 "Cannot Open"
>   UserInfo=0x7f9c5d17b8c0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9c5d176910 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12847.)",
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported.,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open}

Here 's my code :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.videoPlayerView = [[VIMVideoPlayerView alloc] init];
    self.videoPlayerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.videoPlayerView.delegate = self;
    [self.videoPlayerView setVideoFillMode:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];
    [self.videoPlayerView.player enableTimeUpdates];
    [self.videoPlayerView.player enableAirplay];
    [self.view addSubview:self.videoPlayerView];
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_videoPlayerView);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_videoPlayerView]-0-|" options:0   metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_videoPlayerView]-0-|" options:0   metrics:nil views:views]];

    //this is the kind of url I want to load
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://player.vimeo.com/video/51806929"];
    [self.videoPlayerView.player setURL:URL];
    [self.videoPlayerView.player play];
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a URL to a video file (`https://player.vimeo.com/video/51806929`), it's a URL to a webpage.

URLs passed to the video player should be URLs to an actual video file resource.

You can test VIMVideoPlayer out by dropping an mp4 file onto a server and passing that URL to the player.

If you're a Vimeo PRO account user when you request the JSON for a specific video or list of videos from the Vimeo API, you'll see a list of `VideoFile` objects associated with each `video` object. These represent various resolution video files for this particular video. Each has a URL. You can pass this URL to the player.

Let us know if you have questions!

Comment: so in order to play videos in an iOS app a developer has to purchase a Vimeo PRO account? Or can a developer just register his app at the https://developer.vimeo.com/api and he will be able to get the JSON with the files URLs?

Comment: That's correct, only PRO subscribers will see playback URLs in the JSON response for a video object.

Comment: @AlfieHanssen So are you saying it's impossible to play a vimeo video unless the video owner a) has a pro account b) extracts the url to the mp4 and shares it

Comment: @RunLoop, sort of. In order to see progressive and HLS playback URLs in a video object's JSON response from the Vimeo API you the developer must have a Vimeo Pro account. You could take an alternative approach and play the videos via a webview.

Comment: @AlfieHanssen thanks, for the info. I find Vimeo's stance on this baffling. We've had to advise our client to only link to YouTube since using a UIWebView for videos is not an optimal user experience in the context of the app's ui.

Comment: @AlfieHanssen If  I purchase a Vimeo PRO account then it will provide me direct link to my video on vimeo.

Comment: Vimeo supports all forms of mobile playback offered by Youtube (as listed here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/youtube_mobileresources?hl=en#playback). You can play a Vimeo video with the Vimeo application using these helper libraries: https://github.com/vimeo/VIMDeeplink. Additionally, PRO users have direct access to their playable video files, an option Youtube does not offer.

Comment: Just to be clear, PRO account holders only have access to their own video urls, is that correct? Not other users video Urls.  So only JSON response pertaining to the account holders videos would have the urls, and responses from other accounts would not contain them?

Comment: Can the player be used with results where it's been specified that the vimeo video is downloadable?  Letting the user stream a video in the custom player without downloading the file to the device?